# className is not changed to class attribute for custom elements in JSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

In one of my React components, I have the following definition for some custom elements:

```
declare global {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-namespace
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            'd3fc-group': DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>;
            'd3fc-svg': DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>;
        }
    }
}
```

and I return as:

```
return (
    <div ref={d3Container} className='main_layout' data-testid={'chart'}>
        <d3fc-group
            id='group'
            className='hellooo'
            style={{ display: 'flex', height: '100%', width: '100%', flexDirection: 'column' }}
            auto-resize>
        </d3fc-group>
    </div>
);
```

But in the resulting html, "className" is converted to "classname" not "class" attribute.

```
<d3fc-group id="group" classname="hellooo" auto-resize="true" style="display: flex; height: 100%; width: 100%; flex-direction: column;"><div style="flex: 1 1 0%; display: flex; flex-direction: column;"></d3fc-group>
```

How to make it converted to "class" attribute like other components?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like React treats custom elements differently and passes through all attributes directly without any converting the names of React's special attributes. Thus `className` does not get translated to `class`.

You can instead use `class` directly in your case.

See issue discussion: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4933 
and docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html

Answer (score 2):

Please make it simple and use `class` instead of `className`.

*Custom elements DO work in React. You must use class instead of className because the custom element spec requires that we allow users to specify a className attribute and we need to preserve that functionality for custom elements. - Source*

Comment: Did you mean to cite the "Source" of your quote? This *appears* to be [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4933).